# A small detail in Evans' PDE Exericse 7.5

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, weak-convergence, parabolic-pde

The problem is already addressed in [Exercise in Evans, Partial Differential Equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162350/exercise-in-evans-partial-differential-equation?noredirect=1&lq=1), but I cannot get through one small step. Let me phrase it here:

> Assume that $u_k \to u$ weakly in $L^2(0,T;H^1_0)$ and $u_k' \to v$ weakly in $L^2(0,T; H^{-1})$. Let $\phi \in C_c^1(0,T; \mathbb{R})$ and $w \in H^1_0$. Let $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ denotes the pairing between $H^{1}_0$ and $H^{-1}$. Then we have
> $$\langle \int_0^T u_k' \phi dt, w\rangle  = \int_0^T \langle u_k', \phi w \rangle dt. $$

If the pairing is identical to $L^2$ inner product, then the result is just Fubini's. However, I don't know how to see this when it is a $H^{-1}$ pairing. Or should we view the integral as a Riemann sum, then the result follows from linearity? If it is the case, I think we also need some convergence theorem. Could anyone give me some hint on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For strongly measurable functions, we have
\begin{align*}
\langle\int_0^T u_k' \phi \, dt, w \rangle &= \int_0^T \langle u_k' \phi, w\rangle \, dt.
\end{align*}
Note that here $w \in H_0^1(U)$ is independent of $t$. The $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the pairing of the spatial Sobolev spaces; as $\phi$ is a function of time only, for $t \in [0, T]$ $\phi(t)$ is a constant and so can be put in either argument of the pairing on the right hand side, since the pairing is bilinear. Thus $\langle u_k' \phi, w\rangle = \langle u_k', \phi w\rangle$, and putting this in an integral finishes the argument.

Comment: Thank you! I haven't encountered this part before, may I know why strong measurability implies your first equality?

Comment: Do we invoke the fact that for bounded linear operator $T$, and Bochner-integrable $f$, we have $T\int f = \int Tf$, as stated in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral?

Comment: Yeah, I think so; I actually haven't read a proof of this fact myself. It's Theorem 8 in Appendix E of Evans, and for the proof he refers to a book by Yosida.